# What does the Abstract Base Class register method actually do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am confused about the ABC register method.

Take the following code:

```
import io
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class IStream(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def read(self, maxbytes=-1):
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def write(self, data):
        pass

IStream.register(io.IOBase)

f = open('foo.txt')

isinstance(f, Istream) # returns true
```

When you register io.IOBase what exactly happens? Are you saying that IOBase class can only have methods defined by Istream ABC class going forward? What is the benefit of ABC registering other classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply makes `issubclass(io.IOBase, IStream)` return `True` (which then implies that an instance of `io.IOBase` is an instance of `IStream`). It is up to the programmer registering the class to ensure that `io.IOBase` actually *conforms* to the API defined by `IStream`.

The reason is to let you define an interface in the form of `IStream`, and let you indicate that a class that may not have actually inherited from `IStream` satisfies the interface. Essentially, it is just formalized duck typing.

Answer (score 0):

For example, we can replace **`Cat` class** extending **`Animal` class** below:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def sound(self):
        pass

# ↓↓↓ Here ↓↓↓

class Cat(Animal):
    def sound(self):
        print("Meow!!")

# ↑↑↑ Here ↑↑↑

print(issubclass(Cat, Animal))
```

With this code having [**register()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register) below:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def sound(self):
        pass

# ↓↓↓ Here ↓↓↓

class Cat:
    def sound(self):
        print("Meow!!")
        
Animal.register(Cat)

# ↑↑↑ Here ↑↑↑

print(issubclass(Cat, Animal))
```

Then, both of the code above outputs the same result below showing **`Cat` class** is the subclass of **`Animal` class**:

```
True
```